# Logic after tkinter object does not get executed in a class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, inheritance, methods

I have this script where I initialize a tkinter object with some labels, entries, and buttons with commands. when I run the script, the **init** function executes fine and the instance of the tkinter window gets spawned and the buttons work just fine. The problem is that, the logic after the **init** function does not get executed and the tkinter window stays looping for ever unless I hit the exit button and then it just finishes the script. I want to be able to use the inputs from the tkinter.Entry() and the tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() functions to do more stuff later in the application such as loading an excel sheet based on the path passed on the askopenfilename() sections but I can't get it to continue.

Note: I am new to using classes so I believe my mistake is somewhere in the way I am laying down the building blocks of the instance itself. Also, while putting this scrip together so many other questions arised and it has been very hard to find concise answers online. I will post some of those questions here in case someone wants to answer them (not needed though)

1- Do I need to declare every single new variable that come in new methods of the class in the **init** function, if so, why? I just did it here because pycharm game me warning every time I did not do it but not sure what is the reason behind it.

2- When calling a variable on a new method within the class, and the variable is already defined in the **init** fucntion, do I need to include the variable in the arguments section of the method? if so, do I add the variable with the self argument or not?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Define parameters
        self.current_PR_report = ""
        self.new_PR_report = ""
        self.path = ""
        self.raw_excel = None
        self.new_report = None
        self.current_report = ""
      
        # Configure the root window
        self.title("PR Reader")
        self.geometry('250x200')

        # Label
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Merge Problem Reports!")
        self.label.pack()

        # Date Label and Entry
        self.date_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Date (MM-DD-YYYY)")
        self.date_label.pack()
        self.date_label_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.date_label_entry.pack()

        # Run button
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Run", command=self.select_file)
        self.button.pack()

        # Button for closing
        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.destroy)
        self.exit_button.pack(pady=20)

    # Bring Dialog box to obtain Excel files paths
    def select_file(self):
        self.current_PR_report = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            title="Select Current PR Report",
            initialdir="some path",
            filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])

        self.new_PR_report = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            title="Select New PR Report",
            initialdir="some path",
            filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])

        # Load the spreadsheets
        self.new_report = self.read_excel_report(self.new_PR_report)
        self.current_report = self.read_excel_report(self.current_PR_report)

    # Define function to load Excel data
    def read_excel_report(self, path):
        try:
            # sheet_name=None indicates you want a dictionary of data frames, each item in the dictionary
            # representing a different worksheet.
            self.raw_excel = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=-1, engine='openpyxl')
            self.raw_excel = self.raw_excel.fillna('')

            print("data extracted")
            return self.raw_excel
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you tried to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. It seems like it's longer than it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Just reduced it to have just fundamental information. @BryanOakley

Comment: We can't tell anything, because you haven't included the code that calls this.  There's nothing particularly wrong with the code you have provided here, but someone has to create the `App` instance and then call `mainloop`.  That's not here.

Comment: Arguments and class member variables are very different things with different purposes.  You do not need to declare every member variable in `__init__`, as long as you don't try to USE one before you have created it.

Comment: @TimRoberts That is my fault, sorry. Just added the lines to create an instance of App instance with
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

Comment: Are all of those imports necessary to reproduce this?

Comment: OK, when I run your code, it seems to work just fine.  The dialog comes up, I can enter a date, and when I click "run" it brings up the file dialogs.  Do you not see that?

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, `app.mainloop()` will not return until the application exits.  Any work you need done needs to be triggered by the UI handlers.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes until that point the script works fine and I get the same result as you do. The problem is that after that point the script just loops for ever and stays on the box unless I exit the program manually and then process is finished and nothing else gets executed. I want to be able to use the data collected on the tkinter box in the"read_excel_report" method for example

Comment: `raw_excel` does not need to be a `self` variable.  It can be local to the function, since you return it.  Why do you have the `try`/`except` in there?  That could be hiding the issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was using the try/except statements at some point for debugging purposes. I agree I can get rid of it. Also, just to make sure that was not the issue, I placed a print statement on the read_excel_report and it does not get executed, which leaves me with the same issue of the script not passing the tkinter box. 

Thanks for self variable explanation that makes sense now!!

Comment: Running your code as provided produces the correct outputs (prints `data extracted` for twice). You are then left with your original window, which is the expected behaviour because you haven't closed it. What are you expecting it to do once you have selected both files?

Comment: Just realized that if I want the rest of my methods to run I need to call them inside the logic of  the "select_file" method since it is the method called when the "Run" button gets called. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My main issue is that after running the script my other methods were not getting executed. I learned that I not only need to define the methods on my class but also need to call them inside of it. I this case, I had to call them inside the logic of the "select_file" method since it is the method called when the "Run" button gets called.